# pure-react-carousel: all slides visible

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, pure-react-carousel

**Summary**
I am trying to render some slides and the container the slides exist in does not hide the non-active slides. The result is you can see all slides when only one should be visible. Additionally, The slides render outside of the container.

**Attempts**
I'd rather not make my own slide component and try to get it to work since that's the point of using this library. I've tried changing different css styles to see if it works, tried changing some of the content, nothing has fixed it yet.

**Notes**
When I put the component into storybook, the issue goes away. I'm not sure what the difference is, I pass the same props to both.

Comment: I think the issue is with react-carousel.es.css and the webpack config I have. I haven't figured out how to solve my loader issue but if I do and that fixes this, I'll write my own answer.

Comment: Unfortunately found nothing =(. Asked in issues as well in the repo. Maybe w/ my current setup I'm unable to import css files from node_modules. I am not very experienced w/ webpack.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I changed the file to a scss file in node_modules, created an scss file in the same folder as my component, and imported the node_modules scss file into the new scss file.

Comment: in webpack config I'm using style-loader, css-loader, and sass-loader

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to react-carousel.es.css. It's either not imported or not applied for some reason. I had the same issue when forgot to import it